# Error on sign-in: "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, connection-string

I'm moving my site and database from from Azure to GoDaddy.  Everything worked on Azure.

On GoDaddy, the site pulls inventory from the database using either of the two connection strings.  However, when I try to log in I get the error.

I'm new to MVC authentication, so I may be missing something simple that Azure was doing for me.

Here are my sanitized connection strings:

```
<add name="ConnectionString1" 
     connectionString="Server=ServerIP, ThePort;
     Database=DatabaseName;
     User ID=AdminUserID;
     Password=AdminPassword;
     MultipleActiveResultSets=False;
     Encrypt=True;
     TrustServerCertificate=True;
     Connection Timeout=30;" />

<add name="ConnectionString2" 
     connectionString="Data Source=ServerIP, ThePort;
     Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;
     Persist Security Info=True;
     User ID=AdminUserID;
     Password=AdminPassword" />
```

Comment: How about this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/9041524/60761

Comment: Two checks - 1. have you tried Integrated security set to false? 2. TrustServerCertificate needs a valid certificate in the SQL Server instance. Can you confirm either? The 2. is more important and likely cause

Comment: I confirmed the ConfigurationManager pulls the correct connection strings.

Comment: I tried with Integrated Security set to false.  I'm not sure how to confirm the SQL Server instance has a valid cert, so I tried with encrypt set to false and TrustServerCertificate removed.  Would this accomplish the same effect?