# Entity Framework Core - 'Update-Database' not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In my solution I have several .NET Core 2.0 projects:

- App.DataAccess
- App.DataAccess.Migrations
- App.WebApi

In `App.DataAccess.Migrations` (which I want to use as the migrations assembly) I have an `AppDbContextFactory` class:

```
namespace App.DataAccess.Migrations
{
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    using System.IO;

    public sealed class AppDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<AppDbContext>
    {
        public AppDbContextFactory()
        {
            Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public AppDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext> builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext>();

            builder.UseSqlServer(
                connectionString: Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions => sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly(GetType().Namespace));

            return new AppDbContext(builder.Options);
        }
    }
}
```

In the same project, I also have an `appsettings.json` file:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyApp;User ID=sa;Password=SomethingSecret;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}
```

In my `App.WebApi` project, I have the following in my `Startup` class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(ConfigureDatabaseOptions);
    services.AddMvc();
}

private void ConfigureDatabaseOptions(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
{
    builder.UseSqlServer("DefaultConnection", ConfigureSqlServerDatabaseOptions);
}

private void ConfigureSqlServerDatabaseOptions(SqlServerDbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
{
    builder.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(AppDbContextFactory).Namespace);
}
```

In the same project, I've also added the connection string to `appsettings.json`.

**Add-Migration** works.

**Update-Database** throws this error:

> System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not
>   conform to specification starting at index 0.

Why?

Comment: Doesn't work isn't a problem statement. What's actually happening?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Apologies in my frustration I neglected to add the error. Post has been updated.

Comment: Something that may have an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040266/how-to-fix-error-format-of-the-initialization-string-does-not-conform-to-speci

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it. I'm passing "DefaultConnection" as the connection string instead of the connection string **name**:

```
private void ConfigureDatabaseOptions(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
{
    builder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), ConfigureSqlServerDatabaseOptions);
}
```

Comment: Sometimes, EF Core can do that for you by using `.UseSqlServer("name=DefaultConnection")`

Answer (score 1):

The way I could solve the problem was in the following way, in order to understand the solution I placed the name of a fictitious connectionString. it´s solution

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<AuthenticDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString")));
            services.AddIdentity<AplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuthenticDBContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
            services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(configureJson);
        }
```

Comment: AppSetting.Json "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ConnectionString": "Server=Server;Database=Database;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },