# Error in connect to SQL database through CreateUserWizard

Tags: asp.net, createuserwizard

I added a "create User Wizard" to a web Form and change the web.config file to change the database address. I ran this form and filled the fields , then clicked the submit button. This error page was appeared :"Server Error in '/' Application.
Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0. " . After that I checked the connection String that i had entered , that was okey. I checked it on an other application. Here is web.config file :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  
  <connectionStrings>

    <add
      name="MyConnectionString"
      connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-RMNK148;Initial Catalog=MySiteDatabase;User ID=MyUserID;Password=MyPassword"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
  </appSettings>
  
  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="MyProvider">
      <providers >
        <clear/>
        <add
          name="MyProvider"
          type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
          connectionString="MyConnectionString"
          enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
          enablePasswordReset="true" 
          requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
          requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
          passwordFormat="Hashed"
          applicationName="/"
         />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    
    
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
  </system.web>
  
    
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems that your `UserID` parameter is not valid in provided connection string. Try `User ID` (with whitespace) instead:

```
<add name="MyConnectionString"
     connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-RMNK148;Initial Catalog=MySiteDatabase;User ID=MyUserID;Password=MyPassword"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Note that *"format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0"* error always occurs if the connection string is not in correct format, or contains invalid characters (like database password which uses semicolons).

Reference: [SQL Server Connection Strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

Related issue: [Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243008/format-of-the-initialization-string-does-not-conform-to-specification-starting-a)

Comment: thanks Tetsuya , i tried it , but the error still remains.

Comment: as i said , i tested this cs on other application and that connected successfully.

Comment: Can you provide error stack trace? Sometimes it not just caused by incorrect web.config connection string, but usage of another method which requires connection string but you provide connection string key instead.