# Dynamic filtering Datagridview VB

Tags: datagridview

Hey Guys I am getting a problem Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I am a complete beginner so any instructions/solutions will be appreciated.

Imports System.Data.SqlClient
    Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

```
Public Class Form1



Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)      Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim connectionstring As String
    Dim commandtext As String
    Dim da As MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim table As DataTable
    commandtext = "select * From student"
    connectionstring = "Server=*****;Database=Harry;Uid=****;Pwd=****;Allow Zero Datetime=True;"


    Try
        da = New MySqlDataAdapter(commandtext, connectionstring)
        table = New DataTable
        da.Fill(table)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = table

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)



    End Try
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    da = New MySqlDataAdapter
    da.Fill(ds, "student")


    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("student")


End Sub


Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    ds.Tables("student").DefaultView.RowFilter = "student_id LIKE '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%' OR name LIKE '%" & TextBox1.Text & "*'"

End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your problem is the declaration of ds.

As you intend to use it im more than one place try declaring it as a global variable. I dont see anything wrong with the way you do declare it, simpley place the line 'Dim ds As New DataSet' within your class but above the load event.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I now get the error System.argumentexception. Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 69. I click Ok my form loads but then when I type into the textbox - I get the same previous error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Comment: It sounds like either the connection string is incorrect or not set properly. OR there are problems with the SQL permissions. Which explains the initial error! Then the object reference not set to an instance of an object would be explained by the fact you do not have a connection to the database due to the incorrect connection string. I found this thread which may help describe your problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219676/format-of-the-initialization-string-does-not-conform-to-specification-starting-a     It might not match your environment exactly by the principle is the same.

Comment: I think I am doing it all wrong. I have been reading up on and I think  my initial approach was incorrect.