# Connection string format error when deployed to IIS

Tags: entity-framework, iis, connection-string

I have the following connection string in Web.config:

```
<add name="CTRS2Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Edmx.CTRS2.csdl|res://*/Edmx.CTRS2.ssdl|res://*/Edmx.CTRS2.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=SYS2-PC;Initial Catalog=CTRS2;user id=**;password=***;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

It runs fine in deveopment mode. However, when I deploy it to IIS, I get the following error:

```
Format of initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.
```

Comment: I think the answer is in the SO.Please refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219676/format-of-the-initialization-string-does-not-conform-to-specification-starting-a)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `&quot;` values in your connection string with single quotes and you're golden.

See: [Keyword not supported: "data source" initializing Entity Framework Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997035/keyword-not-supported-data-source-initializing-entity-framework-context)