# Connection String Error: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5

Am stock in this a error, some help will be ok.

Am trying to deploy an MVC5 Application to a localhost IIS and after deploying to the system and i have created a database in the system with the same on the application web.config but i figure that when i try to lunch it am having this Error

```
Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.
```

and i did some research and find out that it is from my Connection string and i have tried every thing possible but it is still throwing the same error please some help...

When the application is run on the development machine with .\SQLEXPRESS it works fine so can i make it work on the hosted system.

this is the connection string for the System am trying to host

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=10.0.226.25\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=NNPCUsersDB;  user id=Administrator;password=****; Integrated Security=false" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="NNPCDeportContext" connectionString="data source=10.0.226.25\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=NNPCResourcesDB; user id=Administrator;password=****; Integrated Security=false" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

or should i use

```
source=PPMCW44016\SQLEXPRESS;
```

that is the system SQL Server name

Comment: What am i Missing please??

Comment: use [ConnectionStrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) for validating

Comment: check this - `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219676/format-of-the-initialization-string-does-not-conform-to-specification-starting-a`

Comment: This example is from connectionstrings.com:  `Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;`

Answer (score 1):

The `integrated security=true` and `user id/password` specifications are mutual exclusive.  The user id/password is only for SQL authentication so you should specify `integrated security=false` in that case.

You cannot specify ad-hoc Windows credentials in the connection string.  Assuming identity impersonate=true, specify `integrated security=true` without `user id/password` for Windows authentication using the application pool account.

Comment: @Hurona, update your question with your current connection string.  It may also be a code issue (e.g. empty connection string).

Comment: Am still having the same problem please any more ideas